# Read contents of file into array inside vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

[image: directory structure]

Inside my `media.txt` file, I have:

```
"https://www.dropbox.com/s/******/687.jpg?dl=0",
"https://www.dropbox.com/s/******/0688.jpg?dl=0
```

I have the following Vue carousel component:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <v-card
        class="mx-auto"
        color="#26c6da"
        dark
        max-width="1200"
      >

      <v-carousel>
        <v-carousel-item v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i" :src="item.src"></v-carousel-item>
      </v-carousel>

    </v-card>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
var cache = {};
// const images = require.context('../static/', false, /\.png$|\.jpg/);
// const images = require.context('../static/', false, /\.png$|\.jpg|\.mp4/); // WORKING
const images = require.context('../static/media.txt', false, /\.png$|\.jpg|\.mp4/);
var imagesArray = Array.from(images.keys());
// const images = ["./52lv.PNG", "./Capture1.PNG", "./maps.PNG"]
console.log(images.keys());
console.log('images');
console.log(images);
var constructed = [];
function constructItems(fileNames, constructed) {
  fileNames.forEach(fileName => {
    constructed.push({
      'src': fileName.substr(1)
    })
  });
  return constructed;
}
console.log('items ');
console.log(imagesArray);
// At build-time cache will be populated with all required modules. 
var res = constructItems(imagesArray, constructed);
console.log(res);
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      items: res
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

I want to read the images from the `media.txt` file into an array, then populate the carousel `src` with these. I've been trying with Webpack's `require.context` function, but I'm getting a `module not found` error.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to import a string array (JSON) into a variable. That string array should be delimited by square brackets like this:

```js
[
  "foo",
  "bar"
]
```

[`require.context(dirPath, useSubDirs, filenameRegex)`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext) is not the appropriate API to use here, as that method imports multiple files from a specified directory. For instance, the code below tells Webpack to load `*.png`, `*.jpg`, and `*.mp4` files from the directory named `../static/media.txt` (which presumably is actually a file).

```js
require.context('../static/media.txt', false, /\.png$|\.jpg|\.mp4/) // DON'T DO THIS
```

Instead, you could simply use `require('path/to/file.json')` to import the specified file as a JSON object/array. For example, to import `src/assets/media.json` (containing the array mentioned at the top), the syntax would be:

```js
// e.g., in src/components/Foo.vue
const media = require('../assets/media.json')
console.log(media) // => [ "foo", "bar" ]
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/j7zkk9v999)

Answer (score 3):

You probably should install https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader#getting-started (a loader for webpack read txt files), configure it in your vue.config.js and you should be able to import like this: import txt from 'raw-loader!./file.txt'; instead using require.